# What setting can I change as my email forms don't work with some phones or ESIMs?

Tags: options, email, subdomains

I have tried lots of different things but can't get email working from subdomains. If I use something like CF7 the little wheel just keeps spinning for some people in Japan using ESIMs or VPNs from other countries. If they use WiFi in Japan the form works though... I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help would be great. The main domain works but I only have this problem with the subdomain. A default._domainkey, _adsp._domainkey, TXT, A & MX have all be set in the DNS record as well. I'm happy to try any plugins or is there something I can do in WordPress to fix the problem?